# Use socket.io-client with Express and nodejs to send query to java server

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have a web app built upon Express. The nodejs backend is using a java server to perform some heavy operations. The dialogue between Express and the java server is done using socketio. The nodejs server is the client and uses socket.io-client to send queries to the java server. The javaserver is based upon netty-socketio.

Here is what I am doing in my nodejs app:

```
    var io = require('socket.io-client')
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

    socket.on('connect', function () {

        console.log('0 Connected!');

        socket.emit('myEvent', ['0' ,'here is the query'], function (data) {
          console.log('\tSending query ... waiting for ACK0');
          console.log(data); 
        });

        socket.on('serverResponse', function (data) {
            console.log('\tserverResponse event triggered, data:');
            console.log(data);
        });

    });
```

When calling this script outside my web app everything is working like a charm, but when I call this code from express my client fails to connect (I don't reach the '0 Connected!' line). There are no error messages.

The weird part is that if I am first running my web app, throwing a query, and then start my java server, the client connects to the java server and everything is working (for that query only). Any clues on how to fix that ?

**EDIT 1**

Here is a schema of what I am trying to achieve:

```
client                      javascript backend                   java server
via browser         <--->   node/Express/socketio-client  <--->  netty-socketio           
@client's machine     |     @my server                      |    @my server (the same)
                      |                                     |
                   myDNS:80                           localhost:8080
```

More precisions on the java server. Here is the squeleton:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.setHostname("localhost");
        config.setPort(8080);

        final SocketIOServer server = new SocketIOServer(config);

        server.addEventListener("myEvent", String[].class, new DataListener<String[]>() {

            @Override
            public void onData(final SocketIOClient client, String[] data, final AckRequest ackRequest) {

              //Id of the client
              String id = data[0];

              //Acknowledge the request:
              ackRequest.sendAckData("ACK_"+id);

              //doing some calculations ...
              // ... ... ...
              // ... ... ...

              client.sendEvent("serverResponse", new VoidAckCallback(){
                  @Override
                  protected void onSuccess() {}
              }, "I am the answer from the server");
           }
        });

        server.start();
        System.out.println("[JAVA SERVER INFO] Java server started.");

        Thread.sleep(60000*3);//Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        server.stop();
        System.out.println("[JAVA SERVER INFO] Java server stopped.");
    }

}
```

My web app nodejs backend and my java server are running on the same machine, the communication with socket.io is done via localhost:8080. Once again, the weird thing is that the client's script is working when used outside the express framework, this let me think it might be a compatibility problem between socket.io-client and Express.

**EDIT 2**

I modified my socket.io-client code to see with more details what is happening, I added:

```
  socket.on('connect_error', function(err){
    console.log(err);
  });

  socket.on('connect_timeout', function(){
    console.log("connect_timeout");
  });

  socket.on('reconnect_attempt', function(){
    console.log("reconnect_attempt");
  });
```

When I run the client with the java server switched off, I get a 'connect_error' event. When the java server is on I get no message at all. It seems the connection is neither failing nor successful, nothing happen ... Any idea on how to debug this better ?

**EDIT 3**

Here is the code I am using to handle a request from the browser:

- index.js:

  ```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var controller = require('../controllers/myController.js');

    /* GET home page. */
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
    });

    module.exports = router;

    router.post('/api/getProcessedData', function(req, res, next){
      var text = req.body.text;
      controller.get_processed_data(text, res);
    });
  ```
- myController.js:

  ```
    var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:8080');

    module.exports.get_processed_data = function(text, res) {
      var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
      console.log('starting client');

      socket.on('connect', function () {

        console.log("client connected.");

        socket.emit('myEvent', [timestamp ,text], function (data) {
          console.log('\tSending query ... waiting for ACK');
          console.log(data); 
        });

        socket.on('serverResponse', function (data) {
          console.log('\tserverResponse' event trigged, data:');
          res.send(data);
        });

      });

      socket.on('connect_error', function(err){
        console.log(err);
      });

      socket.on('connect_timeout', function(){
        console.log("connect_timeout");
      });

      socket.on('reconnect_attempt', function(){
        console.log("reconnect_attempt");
      });

      socket.on('reconnecting', function(){
        console.log("reconnecting");
      });
    }
  ```

Comment: What port is your web app running on?  What port is the Java server listening for socket.io connections on?

Comment: I added some information to my initial post, I hope it helps. Do not hesitate if you need more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of your controller is a bit messed up.  Here are some things that are wrong:

1. You connect to the Java server when the module is loaded, but you don't assign a `connect` event handler until the route gets hit.  This means you will normally miss the connect event except when the server isn't yet running.  So, this entirely explains what you observe.  If the java server is already up when you start your Express server, you miss the connect event so you never execute any of the logic in your `get_processed_data()` function.
2. You install a new connect handler every time the route is hit which means you will get multiple event handlers assigned, though because of the first issue, none of them will likely get hit.

If you want the socket.io connection to be continually connected, this would be one way to rewrite the controller:

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:8080');

socket.on('connect', function () {
  console.log("client connected.");
});

socket.on('connect_error', function(err){
  console.log(err);
});

socket.on('connect_timeout', function(){
  console.log("connect_timeout");
});

socket.on('reconnect_attempt', function(){
  console.log("reconnect_attempt");
});

socket.on('reconnecting', function(){
  console.log("reconnecting");
});

var transactionCntr = 0;


module.exports.get_processed_data = function(text, res) {
    var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    var transactionId = transactionCntr++;
    console.log('sending data to client');

    function onResponse(data) {
        // for concurrency reasons, make sure this is the right
        // response.  The server must return the same
        // transactionId that it was sent
        if (data.transactionId === transactionId) {
            console.log('\tserverResponse' event trigged, data:');
            res.send(data);
            socket.off('serverResponse', onResponse);
        }
    }

    socket.on('serverResponse', onResponse);

    // send data and transactionId
    socket.emit('myEvent', [timestamp ,text, transactionId], function (data) {
        console.log('\tSending query ... waiting for ACK');
        console.log(data); 
    });
}
```

Your current structure has an issue in that it does not appear to have a way to determine which response goes with which request and can have concurrency issues.  It would be simpler to just use a separate http request each time because then the response would be uniquely paired with the appropriate request.

With your socket.io connection, you could use some sort of ID in your request/response so you can tell which response belongs to which request.  I've shown how that would work in the express server.  From your Java server, you would have to echo the transactionId back in the response to the Express server so it can track which response goes with which request.

As your code was, if multiple requests for the `'/api/getProcessedData'` route are in play at the same time, the responses from the different requests could easily get mixed up.  This is an architectural problem of the way you're doing things.

---

I'm no Java expert, but it looks to me like this line:

```
Thread.sleep(60000*3);
```

will sleep your thread for 180,000 milliseconds (3 minutes) and then right after that your code calls `server.stop()`.  So, your Java server shuts itself down after 3 minutes.

So, thus you could only connect to your Java server within the first 3 minutes after you started it.

The logical question here is why are you stopping your server at all?

Comment: It is just to test the server, in the final version it will be Thread.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE);. I am just lazy, this way I don't have to click on the terminate process button in eclipse.

Comment: The funny thing is that if I am first running my node server `npm start` and then throw from the web interface, a post request that is going to call my socket.io-client script. And if no java server is listening on `localhost:8080`. Then when I start the java server, the connection is created and the query is handled properly. When a query is emitted and no server is listening, something is happening that bypass the problem. Would it be possible to emulate this behavior for each query emitted ?

Comment: @user3091275 - it sure sounds like your java server just doesn't stay running so it only works when you start it up right when it's needed.

Comment: I doubt it, I am testing the socketio-client script inside and outside of my web app. When used outside the app, after starting the java server I have 3 minutes to throw all the queries I want, the connections are made and the server is answering flawlessly. The only moment it is not working is when using the script with Express.

Comment: @user3091275 - Do you have something else competing for port 8080?

Comment: I just tried using some random port 4252 and got the same behavior (working outside of Express but not within).

Comment: @user3091275 - I don't follow your previous comment.  Do you mean 4252 worked fine outside of Express and you didn't try it inside of Express?

Comment: I tried using port 4252 both outside of Express and inside. Everything is working outside of Express. Inside of Express it is not working, with the exact same output as when using 8080. No `connect_error` or any other events are fired, and no connection either. So within Express the script sees the java server but for some reason nothing is happening.

Comment: @user3091275 - Can you show the code for processing the post operation in Express that uses the socket.io connection?  That seems to be the code that has the issue.

Comment: @user3091275 - OK, the problem is apparent now.  I've outlined what the problem is in my answer.  I need to think more about the best way to solve it.

Comment: @user3091275 - I added one possible coding solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping through this, it is working now.  I also now realize that socket.io may not be the best option for doing this. In my implementation I use the timestamp as Id and the java server is emitting a `serverResponse+ID` event so each request has its own response event. If I had to do this again I would use a standard java http server and throw a POST request from node to java. Nevertheless I learnt a lot setting this up. Thanks again.

Comment: @user3091275 - I don't trust a Javascript timestamp to be unique per transaction since it only has  a resolution of 1ms. So, you're relying on the fact that no two transactions could ever be started in the same ms. I don't honestly know if that's always going to be true.  If the communication here is always initiated by the Express server and the volume of transactions is not high, then it would probably be a better architecture to just use an http request from Express server to the Java server and let the http connection itself keep request and response connected together. Glad it's solved.